# RecyclerView how to pick up the position of the children after the scroll down?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a RecyclerView, and I want to change the Background of the "Items" that I click.
Everything works out well for the "items" that are already in view. But when I drop the scroll, and click on the "item" it selects other items, I click on item 15, and select item 3, when I drop the scroll, the elements that are in view, are with the reset position. that is, I drop to item 15 that did not appear without me using scrool, when I click on it it is in a smaller position. How do I get this?

```
  private void ListViewAdp_ItemClick(object sender, int e)
    {                    
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            if(e == i)
              listView.GetChildAt(i).SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.alt_green);
              else
                listView.GetChildAt(i).SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);                
        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a touch listener on the RecyclerView instead? This prevents you from having to worry about item positions and also gives you a free convenient **onLongClick** event to detect cases where the user has pressed an item for a long time. You can show a context menu or perform other contextual actions.

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the background color for a view that is then being used to display another item as you scroll down.  It is called RecyclerView for a reason!  The views you are modifying are being recycled to display other items.

So it needs to look something like this...

```
private void ListViewAdp_ItemClick(object sender, int e)
{                    
     SelectedPosition = e;
}
```

Where...

```
    public int SelectedPosition
    {
        get => _viewModel.CurrentRowIndex;
        set
        {
            int lastPos = _viewModel.CurrentRowIndex;
            _viewModel.CurrentRowIndex = value;
            NotifyItemChanged(lastPos);
            NotifyItemChanged(value);
        }
    }
```

The item change notification causes the view to be rebound.  This is the time to change the color.

```
  public override void
        OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        if(SelectedPosition == position)
            holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.alt_green);
          else
            holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);        
    }
```